Apart from the different translation time points, what are the differences between translators and interpreters in computers?
I am learning computer programming language. The teacher said that languages represented by c use a compiler, and languages represented by python use an interpreter. The difference between them lies in the translation time. So what other differences are there between interpreter and compiler?

Translators: Translators convert written text from one language to another at a slower pace, focusing on accuracy and detail.
Interpreters: Interpreters deal with real-time spoken language, providing immediate translation during conversations or events.
